# Erro ao instalar Ionic 3 pelo NPM

Tags: ionic, npm

Estou usando linux Manjaro e ao instalar o ionic pelo comando `sudo npm install -g ionic` me retorna esse erro.

```
[mike@mike-pc ~]$ sudo npm install -g ionic
[sudo] senha para mike: 
npm WARN registry Using stale data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ because the host is inaccessible -- are you offline?
npm WARN registry Using stale package data from https://registry.npmjs.org/ due to a request error during revalidation.
npm ERR! code ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! errno ENOTFOUND
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/cross-spawn failed, reason: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND registry.npmjs.org registry.npmjs.org:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-11-09T01_26_32_434Z-debug.log
[mike@mike-pc ~]$ ^C
[mike@mike-pc ~]$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esta ocorrendo um problema entre sua rede e a do npm por isso esta aocntecendo isto , este problema é conhecido pelo pessoal do npm e eles passam que deve ser corrigido com o comando a baixo.

```
npm config get proxy
npm config get https-proxy
```